# Button Color not changing on toggle for multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple buttons in webpage. But trying to change button color for single button on each click. My code is as below. But not working.... Any help?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleColor(id) {
if(document.getElementById(id).style.background !== 'rgb(255,0,0)') {
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = '#FF0000';

}
else  {
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = '#00FF00';
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="1" style="background-color:#00FF00;"  onclick="toggleColor(this.id)">1</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code looks like it's in the middle of a learning session :) I'd say you are not yet ready testing yourself, just keep at it. (Don't want to sound like a douche but it's a better way to learn)

Comment: You probably getting a sintax error on your code, because of this `background !== 'rgb(255,0,0) {`. Try change it to `background !== '#ff0000') {`

Comment: sorry my mistake... but even with #ff0000 its not working....

Comment: Have you tried changing style.background to style.backgroundColor?

Comment: @FreemanLambda  I am not getting even with background-color.

Comment: @FreemanLambda not getting with backgroundColor also

Comment: i didnt found any error in this , and when i m trying to execute it  **its working !!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem stands in the string comparsion

```
if(document.getElementById(id).style.background !== 'rgb(255,0,0)')
```

The actual value of the background, after setting it's color, is `rgb(255, 0, 0)`

Be carefull with the spaces inside the rgb()

Comment: The problem was with spaces within rgb(). Now I got it. thanks

Comment: I also suggest changing from background to backgroundColor, since background is a collection of background related properties. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score 4):

This is working code. Your code is having error. No script tag, not valid if statement.
Use this code it is working one.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.toggle = true;
function toggleColor(id) {
console.log(document.getElementById(id).style.background);
console.log(document.getElementById(id).style.background.indexOf('rgb(0, 255, 0)'));
if(document.getElementById(id).style.background.indexOf('rgb(0, 255, 0)')>0)
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = '#FF0000';
else if(document.getElementById(id).style.background.indexOf('rgb(255, 0, 0)')>0)
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = '#00FF00';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="1" style="background:#00FF00;"  onclick="toggleColor(this.id)">1</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making syntax error in writing your code. put this code inside 
script tag.

```
 <script>
 function toggleColor(id) {
 if(document.getElementById(id).style.background !== 'rgb(255,0,0)') {
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = '#FF0000';

 }
 else  {
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = '#00FF00';
  }
 }
 </script>
```

Hope this solve your problem .

Thank you.

Comment: You edited your code after i saw .....sorry i am checking for other solution but your code working for me.

Comment: No problem. Sorry my mistake

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was just your comparison needed to include spaces. My example passes in the button so that you don't need to get the element again by ID.

Example [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ujocovi/3/)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" id="1" style="background-color:#00FF00;"  onclick="toggleColor(this)">1</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function toggleColor(el) {
if(el.style.background == 'rgb(0, 255, 0)') {
    el.style.background = '#FF0000';
}
else  {
    el.style.background = '#00FF00';
}
}
```